# server not respond after GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT

Tags: ubuntu

After setup GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="cgroup_enable=memory swapaccount=1" and grub updated

my Ubuntu 20.4 LTS server is restarted and OS running, but cannot login via SSH and docker not working.

Comment: To fix this, restart, enter the Grub menu by typing `e`, remove the kernel parameters and continue booting.

Comment: You could also report errors when trying to ssh and messages in the sshd log. Also explain what you mean by "Docker not working".